# can't get user details using graph api after the first call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to develop asp.net app that will get from the URL user and message text, then will send the user the message  above in Teams,

when the app initiate there is sign in and then message is sent to default user which is mine.

the problem is that if i'm trying to change the URL so another message will be sent with same instance of the app the line

```
await Global.graphClient.Users[Global.sValue].Request().Select(u => new {u.DisplayName,u.Mail,u.UserPrincipalName,u.Id}).GetAsync();
```

is crushing (no errors, just the code stops and the app finish loading with no message being sent).

The same line works fine when the app is first initiate in the same function

any one have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that the project was mvc project, i started new one as web api project and implemented the http get function.